# MySql - Error 1064 - Can't Find Syntax Error

Tags: mysql

This is the output from a mysqldump. I haven't changed anything but I'm getting an Error 1064 near line 1 which I'm assuming is the first non-commented line. Can anyone spot my syntax error?

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.30, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: dbname_email
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.30-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8; */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `Newsletter_Emails`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Newsletter_Emails`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `Newsletter_Emails` (`Email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: strange,i executed same c/p code and got no error and table is also created. Are you sure you dont have something above this code?

Comment: There was some comments above this code. I just added them to the post. But that's it.

Comment: I get *"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*/' at line 1"* here at 5.5

Comment: What would cause it near '*/'? Isn't that just a block comment?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8; */;
```

Apparently, it's caused by the `;` delimiter inside the conditional comment. This works as expected:

```
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
```

Comment: Seems like comments with ! will be parsed and executed only in MySQL server version 4.01.01 and above.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic - Not sure of what you mean exactly but there're more details [in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comments.html) if you're curious.

Comment: That's the only error I found in your code. Please note that, for some reason, the error message always points to line 1. Try removing lines until you find the next guilty one.

Comment: Just removed each line one by one and could not find the guilty line.

Comment: Do you still get the same error with no lines? Are you by chance running SQL from a UTF-8 file with BOM?